# Time vs Calendar in Android Wear watch faces?

Tags: android, calendar

I've been developing a few watch faces for Android wear. After viewing the default Digital project in Android Studios I found out it uses the class `android.text.format.Time` to retrieve the time, which is deprecated, and the API suggests using `GregorianCalendar` instead.

If it is deprecated, it is still recommended to use the `Time` class while working with watch faces? My assumption was that if it was not, the sample project would have already been updated. I've found out that the time can be equally retrieved using `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, or a `Formatter` with a Calendar object. Can someone enlightenment me to the preferred way to handle this or will any method work?

Comment: Personally I use the Calendar, SimpleDateFormat/Formatter option.  I've noticed many here suggest Joda time for time related functions.

Comment: Do I need to register a Broadcast Receiver for handling time zone changes on SimpleDateFormat? Joda seems like a nice alternative, but I'm already in to deep to rework the whole thing right now. I'm not sure if my watch face will be screwed up once timezone is changed, or if it will handle it.

Comment: To anyone reading this in the future. I've found out that my watch face does get updated if I manually change the timezones in Settings, so I don't see the need for a BroadcastReceiver. (I'm using SimpleDateFormat as backend for my time formatting and it automatically invalidates the watch when it happens). I've also found out allocations of Calendar consume less time than SDF.